# Have .git folder, how to host?

Tags: git

I had a GitLab instance that blew up and all I have left is the bare `.git` directories that were in `/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/`. Ultimately I'd like to host them on Bitbucket.

The `.git` directories are available on a public URL, but when trying to import them into Bitbucket using https://bitbucket.org/repo/import it says "No repository exists at that URL".

Could someone please advise how to get from having bare `.git` directories to having a usable hosted remote repo?

Comment: using git checkout may be?http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to the directory where the `.git` directory is inside and make `git status` or `gitk` to inspect the situation.

`git checkout master` would checkout the master branch (if it exists).

If `gitk` or `git status` gives an error this can help you to further track down what to do.

The next thing to check would be the file `.git/config` where some important information about the repository is inside.

You could also try to clone the repository using

```
git clone file:///var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/
```

This would give you a clone of the original repository where you can play around without giving a danger to the original repository.

Comment: The repos can be cloned locally and `git status` reports that all is fine. The problem is how to import the bare repositories into something like Bitbucket. Note that Git is installed on the server on which the `.git` dirs are and browsing the server remotely shows everything there, but trying to clone remotely says `fatal: repository 'http://domain.com/repo.git/' not found`

Comment: If you can clone locally it is very easy: create a repo with github or bitbucket. It will show you that you should do `git init` followed by `git add remote ...` followed by `git push`. You skip the `git init` and just add the remote of your new repo and push it - there it should be in bitbucket!